# What is the default projection in Leaflet?

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, tiles, leaflet

I've read an API documentation for Leaflet on its site, but I can't realize: what is a default projection to view maps? It was written about spherical and elliptical Mercator and Equirectangular - so which of this three? Or does it depend on tile server I use, or it doesn't depend since leaflet reproject tiles instantly on-the-fly before adding on the screen?

Actually i can't understand what projection i need to save geoJSON files in QGIS. To display correctly on the leaflet map, json coords should be lat-long, not x-y. But if i try to save it in Equirectangular - coords will be x-y..?

Answer (score 34):

Leaflet's default projection is [EPSG:3857](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/EPSG:3857), also known as "Google Mercator" or "Web Mercator" and sometimes designated with the number "900913". This projection is what most slippy tile based maps use, including the common tile sets from Google, Bing, OpenStreetMap, and others. You can easily use this projection in QGIS by selecting "Google Mercator EPSG:900913".

Leaflet has some basic support for displaying maps in other projections. Most folks who do that seem to use the addon [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to perform the projection.

Comment: In QGIS 2.0.1, EPSG:3857 is referred to as `WGS84 / Pseudo Mercator` in the _Projected Coordinate Systems-->Mercator_ subsection.