# How to convert CRS projection of a map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am totally new to GIS. I have a QGIS project. I am adding the screenshot.

[image]

As you can see the map is sort of rectangle in projection.  How can I project it like this (without the grids)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapefile from Natural Earth contains the south pole. The Mercator projection is not able to render that point for mathematical reasons (it would be in inifinity).

What you can do:

1. Set Project CRS from Layer (that would be EPSG:4326)
2. switch to edit mode
3. Delete the bottom line of the antarctic
4. save the layer
5. Change Project CRS to EPSG:3857

[image]

If you want an exact square, cut off the antarctic until 85.01 degrees south.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a Mercator Projection. Try to save-as your shapefile assigning the WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857) projection or assign this projection to your project (using transformation on the fly).

See also: [What is the standard Mercator projection?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/what-is-the-standard-mercator-projection)

Comment: I am trying transformation on the fly but it is not able to render properly . Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry - it should be this one: WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857)  See also: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/what-is-the-standard-mercator-projection For me this works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Is it a shapefile your using? If so open the .prj file with any text editor and look for tye word  "mercator" if you dont see that but see WGS84 than use ESPG:4326. Going off the screenshot its one of those, as those are really the only two that people make available for download